# Mongodb IsoDate and the issue with if-modified-since on microservices

Tags: java, mongodb, microservices

When I insert a document on my MongoDB using spring data, I do the following:

```
Update update = new Update();
update.currentDate("lastModified");
mongoTemplate.upsert(query, update, MyDocument.class);
```

I'm using the currentDate of MongoDB, because I want to save the date that MyDocument was last modified with the date where my MongoDB database is located.

Based on the [spec](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt):

> The If-Modified-Since request-header field is used with a method to
>      make it conditional: if the requested variant has not been modified
>      since the time specified in this field, an entity will not be
>      returned from the server; instead, a 304 (not modified) response will
>      be returned without any message-body.

So, the purpose of saving this date is to verify if MyDocument was modified or not based on the received date.

So, when I execute the update, the following IsoDate is created on the database:

```
ISODate("2016-12-02T12:11:33.083Z")
```

So, when a client wants to know if the document has changed, they send me back this date, and I query on the database:

```
    Query query = new Query(where("id").is(filter.getId()));
    Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("lastModified").gt(filter.getLastModified());
    query.addCriteria(criteria);
    return mongoTemplate.findOne(query, MyDocument.class);
```

This works perfectly, except for one problem: The spec says that the header if-modified-since has the following format:

> If-Modified-Since: Sat, 29 Oct 1994 19:43:31 GMT

Which means that the milliseconds is not passed on the if-modified-since header. However, MongoDB IsoDate saves the current date with milliseconds. So, when two dates are exactly the same, the query will not return 304 Not Modified, but it will return the entire resource, because the query will be the following:

```
{ "id" : 123, "lastModified" : { "$gt" : { $java : 2016-12-02T12:11:39.000Z } } }
```

Since the client does not send the milliseconds, the java put the milliseconds as zeros ( 2016-12-02T12:11:39.**000**Z), which means that 
the date on my database is greater than the date sended by my client:

2016-12-02T12:11:33.083Z > 2016-12-02T12:11:39.000Z

Because of the 83 milliseconds.

**The final question is**: What it is the correct way to solve this problem, and work correctly as the specs for if-modified-since suggests?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the date format mentioned in the spec is just an example. you can change the date format for if-modified-since to match what your sever is expecting. How is that being generated now ? I mean which library is doing that for you.

Comment: The header of the browser just does not accept the milliseconds. So, the spec is not just an example. It is how it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the last modified date millis to max milliseconds before comparsion This will technically negate the milliseconds offset.

```
public static Date setMaxMillis(Date day,Calendar cal) {
    cal.setTime(day);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cal.getMaximum(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
    return cal.getTime();
}

Query query = new Query(where("id").is(filter.getId()));
Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("lastModified").gt(setMaxMillis(filter.getLastModified(),Calendar.getInstance()));
query.addCriteria(criteria);
return mongoTemplate.findOne(query, MyDocument.class);
```

Comment: This solves the problem. But, is this the correct way for solving the problem? Or, there is no correct pattern for solving this?

Comment: I think it's a workaround but you are dealing with two different date entries one with millis and one without millis. This answer was to address how we can bridge them. A right solution would be to get them with same date and time component.